# How to save same object multiple times use Spring Data?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I want save an object multiple times, the code below can not work:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    repository.save(object);
}
```

Then I change the source to:

```
List<SomeObject> objectList = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    objectList.add(object);
}
repository.save(object);
```

But it also can not work, It only save the object one time to database.

Maybe because it point to one instance, but I want to know if there is an easy way to save an object multiple times?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to `INSERT` 5 new rows, or `UPSERT` one?
You probably will need to change the primary key before each `repository.save` call, if you want new entries every time

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#saveAll-java.lang.Iterable- ?

Comment: You have to create seperate objects if you want to have multiple entries in the database. `objectList.add(new Object());`and then `repository.saveAll(objectList);`

Comment: What does JPA/sql logging say is happening? This is to confirm how the JPA object is working with the cache

Comment: @RobinJonsson Van Belle When I use Spring BeanUtils to copy the object 5 time and insert into database it works. But I want to know if spring have a easy way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with Spring data and might misunderstand the problem but generally there is no point to save the same object many times.

You need to explicitly create a clone/copy (or so) of an instance and save all these instances separately if you need multiple instances in database.

For example add creating new instance in a loop that saves the object.

Answer (score 6):

It saves only 1  time the object because you are using the same instance every times.

So the first time you use `object`, so now it has an `ID,` then you use object again, but as we said it has an id so instead to save it, yours program **update** it inside you db.

For example if you do this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    repository.save(new Object());
}
```

Or if you have a list of Objects, like

```
List<SomeObject> objectList = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    objectList.add(object);
}
```

you could do this:

```
repository.saveAll(objectList);
```

Now you find 5 rows inside your table

Comment: Avoid persisting in a loop. Use `CrudRepository#saveAll` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  BUT, I user `org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository` interface, and it have no `saveAll()` method. But in the `save(Iterable<S> entities)` method, it's comment as_Saves all given entities._,but it not work.

Comment: Now I use Spring BeanUtil to copy the bean 5 times, and successfully insert into database. Is this the only way?

Comment: @YOUNG If you are using CRUD Repo i think you could use the save for a single entity but also for a collection..

Answer (score 0):

Using the constructor, you can save same object multiple time:

```
Repository.save(new object(String name,String age));
```