# How to receive multiple RequestBody in a controller and save it according to its type in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am new to spring boot, and Thank you in advance. I am facing a problem: I would like to receive two types of object in the controller, using the @ResponseBody, then save them.

I have two models

```
public class Person {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
}

public class Human {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c
}
```

By doing something like this:

```
@PostMapping(value="/save")
public void savePerson(@RequestBody Person person,  @RequestBody Human human) {
    personRepo.save(person);
    humanRepo.save(human);          
}
```

I want to save person and human on the same request. How to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save same object multiple times use Spring Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46602283/how-to-save-same-object-multiple-times-use-spring-data)

Comment: Your code looks fine. What is the problem?

Comment: It only saves person information but shows null for human  but I wants to save person and human at the same time on the same request as both have same fields

Comment: so `human` is `null`? Or does it have the same values as `person`? Please clarify.

Comment: Yes both will have the same value

Comment: Is Human a child class of Person or vice-versa ? Please post your POST request body.

Comment: Then where does it "show `null` for human"? Please state what the actual problem is.

Comment: @NiceBooks No there are independent

Comment: When I do the post method it will show null for human but not for person

Answer (score 1):

Is Person and Human the same 'Entity'? I mean are the values from the post request the same?

If yes I would remove Human from the Arguments and create it based on Person

```
@PostMapping(value="/save")
public void savePerson(@RequestBody Person person) {
      
        Human human = mapPersonToHuman(); 
        personRepo.save(person);
        humanRepo.save(human);          
}
```

Otherwise if person and human are two different things,
I would create a new Wrapper Object so you can a new messages with both entities.

```
public class PersonHumanWrapper{
    Person person;
    Human human;
}
```

Comment: Thank You for the answer but it only saves person data whereas human data is null. I want to save on both entities with the only post of a person as both have the same column header and datatype

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is: create an object with these two objects inside:

```
public class PersonAndHuman {

    private Person person;
    private Human human;

    // getters and setters...
}
```

And your controller should receive this object:

```
@PostMapping(value="/save")
public void savePerson(@RequestBody PersonAndHuman personAndHuman) {
    personRepo.save(personAndHuman.getPerson());
    humanRepo.save(personAndHuman.getHuman());          
}
```

Now, if you are using JSON to make the post, do something like:

```
{
   "human" : {
       //body here
   },
   "person": {
       //body here
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank You for the answer but what I am looking for is I want to post in both human and person with only  { "human": {} }. I meant to say it should post on both with just human post.

Comment: Can you update the question with your possible json body? maybe I can update my answer as well.